# Send 200 response in caddy reverse proxy before forwarding the request

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

Is it possible to send a 200 request to the server calling a reverse proxy, irrespective of whether the proxy server is available or not?
The reason is when the calling server gets non-200 HTTP codes for some threshold value continuously, it will stop sending the requests for that day.

Current caddy config

```
abc.xyz.com {
    reverse_proxy {
    to localhost:23003
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can try this:

```
abc.xyz.com {
    reverse_proxy {
    to localhost:23003
    @name {
        status 500
    }
    replace_status @name 200
  }
}
```

the document: [Intercepting responses](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy#intercepting-responses)